# Fewer stations with Public Transit API v8 than with v3

Tags: api, here-api, transit

So far I use the Transit Public API v3 and now I want to switch to v8. But with the v8 I get less stations.

**Example:**

**v3** *(result 13 stations)*: [https://transit.api.here.com/v3/stations/by_geocoord.json?center=48.1450106,11.5941866&radius=800&max=50&app_id=[myAppId]&app_code=[myAppCode]](https://transit.api.here.com/v3/stations/by_geocoord.json?center=48.1450106,11.5941866&radius=800&max=50&app_id=%5BmyAppId%5D&app_code=%5BmyAppCode%5D)

**v8** *(same location, but only 5 stations)*: [https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?in=48.1450106,11.5941866;r=800&return=transport&max=50&apiKey=[myApiKey]](https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?in=48.1450106,11.5941866;r=800&return=transport&max=50&apiKey=%5BmyApiKey%5D)

It seems that the parameter for radius is not recognized correctly. However, the URL syntax should be correct.